# Why can't I view a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am setting up a Linux web server running apache.  I uploaded and untared my web sites files.  The files in the main directory are all visible when I am SSH'd into the system.  However, I am blocked from all subdirectories.
If I write:

```
# cd images
```

Then I get the error:

```
-bash: cd: images: Permission denied
```

I am signed in as ec2-user.  I untarred the stuff as ec2-user and I doubt there was any permissions in the tar file since I created the archive on a Windows system.
The weird thing is that I am the owner of this directory.  Here is a snippet of the command:
ls -l

```
drw-rw-r-- 19 ec2-user ec2-user      4096 May  4 04:09 images
```

When I do "sudo su" and then type the command cd images everything is fine.
Why do I get "Permission denied" as ec2-user if I am the owner and have rw permission?

Answer (score 2):

You need execute permission too:

```
chmod +x images
```

should take care of it. The execute permission for directories translates to a "traverse directory" permission.

Comment: The funny thing is, for searching and listing, you just need the `r` bit, while for using it, you need `x`. SO it is perfectly valid to have a directiry with `rw-`  which can be listed, but not used, or to have one with `--x` where files can be used from if you exactly know how they are named.

Answer (score 1):

It misses executable bit on the directory which is essential to be able to `cd` in there.

A quick fix would be to run in the directory where you unpacked your stuff:

```
# find . -type d | xargs chmod a+x
```

If you have directories with spaces in them, use the following:

```
# find . -type d -exec chmod a+x "{}" \;
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked to a point.  Now as ec2-user I can "cd images".  But any subdirectories below "images" I am now blocked from.  Can this command be modified to include all levels of subdirs?

Comment: `find` should have taken care of all sub-dirs as well. Can you run just `find . -type d` and see whether it lists all the subdirectories? Also, do you have directories with spaces in the names?

Comment: If you are aware that your command has trouble with spaces, you should modify it in the first place: `find . -type d | xargs -d \\n chmod a+x` or `find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+x` or just `find . -type d -exec xargs chmod a+x {} +`.

Comment: @glglgl: totally agree. I'm a bit slow after a long night :)

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work after I ran the command again.  It was a bit weird.  Every time I ran the command it gave me access to another level of subdirectories.  No, I didn't have any spaces so I just used your first command.